# Cannot access S3 object even though all indications are that I should including policy simulator. Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I can use this policy to upload files to my bucket from user A, in group Z.  A different user in group B also is in group Z and therefore has the same policy. However, I cannot read the file when logged in as B to the AWS management console.  I'm especially mystified because according to the Policy Simulator, this policy (plus the Admin access user B has) should fully enable B to see the file in question.

Instead, user B only gets `Access Denied`.

Help?  I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

My complete (if redacted) group policy is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

My auto-generated bucket policy is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "S3-Console-Auto-Gen-Policy-1645709424074",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "S3PolicyStmt-DO-NOT-MODIFY-1645709423946",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logging.s3.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
    }
]
```

}

My bucket has Block Public Access turned on.

Comment: I presume that both IAM users are in the same AWS account. Do any of the policies in group B (or any other policies that user B has that user A does not have) include a relevant deny clause?

Comment: Good question.  Both users are created in my own, brand new AWS account.  There are no deny clauses in either.

Comment: What are you doing to generate the error? What do you mean by "I cannot read the file" -- are you saying that you cannot list the bucket, or see the object listed, or are you trying to Download the object? Also, what is the complete error message and where is it displayed?

Comment: The web url for the file should be "https://<my-bucket>.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/updated.txt".  Inside the same browser with which I am logged into my user B, I do an http get on that URL.  The result is an xml-based error stating that Access is Denied.

Comment: Browsing `https://mybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/updated.txt` requires the object to be public. The browser's GET request is unauthenticated.

Comment: @jarmod well crap.  I guess I made too many assumptions about how my login would be respected.  Is there any way for me to easily access the file beyond opening it up to the universe, or building a web server?

Comment: You can generate a pre-signed URL for the object that is time-limited and is signed so includes all the auth needed. If you log into the AWS console, navigate to S3, and download an object, you'll see that under the covers the AWS console uses a pre-signed URL to allow your browser to fetch that object.

Comment: That's all I needed.  If you'd like to get credit please add an answer and I'll mark it and upvote.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that even though you are logged into the AWS console, your authentication does not extend to downloading an S3 object via a simple HTTP GET of the object at `https://mybucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/myfile.png`, as would happen if you pasted that URL into a new tab.

Instead, you can generate and use an S3 pre-signed URL to download the object. A pre-signed URL is time-limited and is signed with your secret key so it includes all the auth needed to download the object.

You can use the S3 console, awscli, or any AWS SDK to generate a pre-signed S3 URL, for example:

```
aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/myfile.png
```

Note that pre-signed URLs behave somewhat like a bearer token. Whoever has the pre-signed URL can use it to download the object, until it expires.

You can also download individual objects, or even entire buckets of objects, using the awscli (with appropriate authentication).